# Source voltage and capacitance

Tags: voltage, batteries, capacitor, circuit-analysis

Does changing the source voltage (i.e. voltage of the battery) affect how long it takes for a capacitor to charge in a circuit?

Am I right in saying that since the capacitor charges until it reaches the source voltage that a larger source voltage will mean that it takes longer? But if the capacitance is the same then how does this work? 
[image]

Comment: Voltage difference always controls charge current limited only by sum of all series resistance in in each part including source and cap.

Comment: First, what circuit are you thinking of (please include a schematic)? Second, how do you define "charged"? Do you mean when the voltage on the capacitor reaches some fixed value like 5 V? Or do you mean when it reaches some fraction of the source voltage (like 95%)? Or something else?

Comment: I have just edited the question, I mean that if the battery voltage is changed, will there be a longer time period between when the LED is on and off (since that depends on the capacitor charging and discharging).

Comment: It's not a 'how long does capacitor take to charge' question, it's an 'analyse this circuit's threshholds question', which is more specific and harder. You should alter the title so we don't get dragged here by mistake.